# Change alias of Exchange Online mailbox

Tags: active-directory, exchange, microsoft-office-365

Our Active Directory is synced to Exchange Online using AD Connect.

After renaming a user I have noticed the Alias field in Exchange Online remains unchanged.

Changing it online fails with this message:

> The operation on mailbox "John.Smith" failed because it's out of the current user's write scope. The action 'Set-Mailbox', 'Alias,EmailAddresses', can't be performed on the object 'John Smith' because the object is being synchronized from your on-premises organization. This action should be performed on the object in your on-premises organization.

In AD, there is no where I am able to change it.  I have found solutions that state I should change the mailNickName attribute, but this does not appear in the Attribute Editor.

So I followed method 2 of [this guide](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2824766/alias-or-mailnickname-are-changed-for-a-synced-user) and modified the powershell to be this:

```
Get-ADUser -Properties * -Filter {name -like "John.Smith"} | set-aduser -replace @{mailnickname="John.Smith"}
```

Then I ran AD Connect delta sync.  But it does nothing, the original Alias is still there.

Comment: You should not be doing `-properties * ` just to look up the name of an account. that way you're returning *all* the properties in the account rather than just the one(s) you need, making your queries slow and inefficient. Since `name` is a default property, you don't need to do anything special: `Get-ADUser  -Filter 'name -like "John.Smith"'` is all you need

Comment: ugh, I just found the MSFT article where you got that snippet from - nice when the "experts" hand out bad examples

Answer (score 1):

Please double check in ADSI. Or did you find proxyaddress, please try to change this, the ProxyAddresses attribute is where the aliases are stored.

Did you ever install Exchange on-premises server in this environment? If not, you could extend Active Directory schema to include Exchange attributes:

http://guides.appriver.com/m/89074/l/698027-extend-active-directory-schema-to-include-exchange-attributes

Answer (score 0):

The KB is the solution. And I test on my side. I just change the mailNickName attribute in ADUC and then do a manual sync via Azure AD Connect, it is synced correctly to Exchange Online:
[image]
[image]

You could test another account and check if this issue is only with this account.

In addition , you could check if there is any sync error in AAD connect:

Troubleshoot an object that is not synchronizing with Azure Active Directory
From https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/tshoot-connect-object-not-syncing

Comment: The mailNickname attribute does not appear anywhere. Therefore I cannot edit it